# Python: Retrieving and renaming indexed files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, file-management

I created a script to rename indexed files in a given directory

e.g If the directory has the following files >> (bar001.txt, bar004.txt, bar007.txt, foo2.txt, foo5.txt, morty.dat, rick.py). My script should be able to rename 'only' the indexed files and close gaps like this >> (bar001.txt, bar002.txt, bar003.txt, foo1.txt, foo2.txt...).

I put the full script below which doesn't work. The error is logical because no error messages are given but files in the directory remain unchanged.

```
#! python3

import os, re

working_dir = os.path.abspath('.')

# A regex pattern that matches files with prefix,numbering and then extension
pattern = re.compile(r'''
    ^(.*?)        # text before the file number
    (\d+)         # file index
    (\.([a-z]+))$ # file extension
''',re.VERBOSE)

# Method that renames the items of an array
def rename(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        matchObj = pattern.search(array[i])
        temp = list(matchObj.group(2))
        temp[-1] = str(i+1)
        index = ''.join(temp)
        array[i] = matchObj.group(1) + index + matchObj.group(3)
    return(array)

array = []
directory = sorted(os.listdir('.'))

for item in directory:
    matchObj = pattern.search(item)
    if not matchObj:
        continue
    if len(array) == 0 or matchObj.group(1) in array[0]:
        array.append(item)
    else:
        temp = array
        newNames = rename(temp)
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            os.rename(os.path.join(working_dir,temp[i]),
                        os.path.join(working_dir,newNames[i]))
        array.clear() #reset array for other files
        array.append(item)
```

Comment: I assume that you also want `bar005.txt` and `bar006.txt`?

Comment: Renaming them to what?

Comment: Actually, no. You're meant to close the gap by renaming the later files. Your idea is slightly more tasking. I might consider tackling it on my own once I, or if I, get past this.

Comment: e.g spam01, spam03 , spam04 should be renamed to spam01, spam02, spam 03. This is what I mean by closing gaps by renaming. So basically, renaming the later files using the format of the first file and index of the first.

Comment: Alright, so if there are three files beginning with `spam`, they should end in 01, 02, 03.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Do you care whether you rename *all* files, or just the ones that you need to fill the gaps?

Comment: Only indexed files. That's why I have the regex to pick those out..

Comment: I meant something different, but nevermind. It doesn't change the implementation all that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise, you want to find every file whose name ends with a number and
fill in the gaps for every set of files that have the same name, save for the number suffix. You **don't** want to create any new files; rather, the ones with the *highest* numbers should be used to fill the gaps.

Since this summary translates rather nicely into code, I will do so rather than working off of your code.

```
import re
import os

from os import path

folder  = 'path/to/folder/'
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\d+)(\.[a-z]+)$')
summary = {}

for fn in os.listdir(folder):
  m = pattern.match(fn)
  if m and path.isfile(path.join(folder, fn)):
    # Create a key if there isn't one, add the 'index' to the set
    # The first item in the tuple - len(n) - tells use how the numbers should be formatted later on
    name, n, ext = m.groups()
    summary.setdefault((name, ext), (len(n), set()))[1].add(int(n))

for (name, ext), (n, current) in summary.items():
  required = set(range(1, len(current)+1)) # You want these
  gaps     = required - current            # You're missing these
  superfluous = current - required         # You don't need these, so they should be renamed to fill the gaps

  assert(len(gaps) == len(superfluous)), 'Something has gone wrong'

  for old, new in zip(superfluous, gaps):
      oldname = '{name}{n:>0{pad}}{ext}'.format(pad=n, name=name, n=old, ext=ext)
      newname = '{name}{n:>0{pad}}{ext}'.format(pad=n, name=name, n=new, ext=ext)

      print('{old} should be replaced with {new}'.format(old=oldname, new=newname))
```

That about covers it I think.

Comment: It doesn't work. It prints that the files should have been replaced but they haven't.

Comment: Look at the code. I'm simply telling you what you need to do. Replace the `print` with the renaming logic and you're sorted.

Comment: That makes much more sense

Comment: Good. Do you want to accept the answer in that case, to wrap up?

Comment: `zip` pairs up the items in two or more collections (eg. `zip('123', 'abc')` will give you `('1', 'a')`, then `('2', 'b')` and finally `('3', 'c')`)

Comment: Sets are collections that allow duplicates, much like [mathematical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)).

Comment: They allow certain operations that are very useful in this case. For instance, we can find the items that are in one set but not the other (this is how I figure out what the gaps are: `current - required`)

Comment: I think you should try putting in your renaming logic. Because I can't apply mine on your script. I also think you need to tweak something. I just  made a sample folder with some text random text files (foo(1,3,5,7).txt then also bar(1,4,12,15).txt. It said : `bar12.txt should be replaced with bar1.txt`. It also got the gaps inaccurately

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: As for the renaming, could you explain what the exact problem is?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Fixed the logic error: I accidentally zipped `superfluous` with `required` instead of `gaps`.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that. I'm going back and forth between SO and my own editor.

Comment: what does .add()  do and also I've never see ':>0' in a string formatting?

Comment: `:` separates the key name from the format specifier. `>0{pad}` means left-pad with zeroes so that the number has exactly {pad} digits. More [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html).

Comment: `.add()` is a `set` method. It's a pretty versatile class, I highly recommend reading up on them ([here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)) and maybe experimenting in the interactive console.

Comment: Is there a place where I can learn about mappings, iterators, sets and other structures? I've been looking for one

Comment: Well apart from this site and the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html), there's an endless stream of tutorials and blogposts you could find on Google. I also recommend playing around with concepts in the Python REPL to get a feel for then.